# what is "stat information" in a git index?

Tags: git, git-index

In git documentation (like git-checkout-index http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-checkout-index ), there are references to "stat information" in the index file. What is this mysterious "stat information"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's information that would be returned by [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) - in particular, file permissions, since that's what's actually tracked. (Other information includes timestamps, filesize, user/group owners, and the inode.)

There's also a command-line program [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) which is essentially a wrapper for that system call; try `stat <file>` and you'll see all that kind of information.

Comment: And you can use `git ls-files --debug` to see what git has cached.