# how does git check if a merge is needed?

Tags: git, git-merge

According to [documentation](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index), `git update-index --refresh` does this:

> Looks at the current index and checks to see if merges or updates are needed by checking stat() information.

**What does it mean that git "checks to see if merges or updates are needed"?** Does git keep an arbitrary flag somewhere saying "mergeme" after certain operations?

Also, I think I understand `stat` ( [what is "stat information" in a git index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234463/what-is-stat-information-in-a-git-index) ), but I don't see how knowing things like [the UID](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) help git at all know if a merge needs to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description is a little misleading. This command check if the working copy has diverged from the index. In this context, a merge means that you'll need to use `git add`, `git rm` or `git checkout` to bring the index and the working copy in sync. This has nothing to do with `git merge`.

The index store a snapshot of the working copy file `stat` information in order to optimize the detection of modification by the user. It is updated every time those modification are inserted into the staging area (`git add`, `git rm`) or when the working copy modification are discarded (`git checkout`, `git reset`, ...).