# What does `git-add --refresh` do?

Tags: git

```
$ man git-add     # says:
```

> ```
>   --refresh
>        Don’t add the file(s), but only refresh their stat() information in the index.
> ```

What is `stat()`?

I can't seem to find any git documentation on it.  I'm guessing it's short for 'status' or something.

Comment: Try `man stat`.

Comment: The answer to the question [what is “stat information” in a git index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234463/what-is-stat-information-in-a-git-index) seems to be what you are searching for.

Comment: @FlyingFoX good find!

Comment: Sorry but the supposedly 'duplicate' Q doesn't mention `git-add` nor `--refresh`.